# Difference between ./ and ../

Tags: web

Might be a fairly simple question to ask, however, I would love to know the difference between the two. I see them being used a lot when doing relative file linking for web design however I don't know the difference between the two.

```
./
../
```

Are they different/same in terms of behavior?

Comment: `.` is the current directory. `..` is the parent directory of the current directory. This has nothing to do with `web` so I'm not sure why you have that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

´./´ stands for the current directory.
´../´ stands for the parent directory.

e.g. you are looking in directory ´C:\base\level1´, then:
´./´ equals ´C:\base\level1´
´../´ equals ´C:\base´